# dojo ValuePickerDatePicker on Android device

Tags: javascript, android, dojo

The Dojo mobile DatePicker - **dojox.mobile.ValuePickerDatePicker** - is behaving incorrectly:
Clicking on the plus(+) and minus(-) buttons for the year updates the day value and the otherway around.

This only appears on the device and never in a browser during development. Have reproduced on multiple Android devices.
This is also somewhat intermittent in that the steps to reproduce are not exactly the same every time. However once it starts to go wrong it continues to be wrong...

**To reproduce**: in the Date Picker widget, repeatedly and randomly click on the plus(+) and minus(-) buttons and on the editable fields. Eventually the fields will start to update incorrectly. (I would like it to be more predictable)
Have never reproduced the error on my PC/MAC.
I have a suspicion that the predictive text on the device is interfering, but I have no proof of that.
You can reproduce the error with the widget/Date Picker on its own. Tested with Dojo version 1.9.4 and 1.10.1. The Date Picker is created declaratively:

```
<div id="dateSelectorDatePicker" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ValuePickerDatePicker" data-dojo-props="slotOrder:[2,1,0]"></div>
```

Try this example in your browser on a Android device http://jsfiddle.net/sport_johan/q943mbrs/1/

Comment: Johan, thanks for the report - I've forwarded this to the developers to have a look.

Comment: Johan, can you provide exact device details? model, OS version, etc... thus far, attempts to reproduce the issue were not fruitful.

Comment: @IdanAdar - I experience the same problem with ValueDatePicker. Except this starts right away. I also use Worklight and Dojo 1.9.4

Comment: Thanks. Still need device details and reproduction steps as I mentioned in my previous comment

Comment: @IdanAdar, I have reproduced this on a Samsung Tab4 running Android 4.4.2 and on a Samsung S3 running Android 4.3.

Comment: @IdanAdar, I think I might have found the root cause and a work around, but will do some more testing before adding a proper answer here (if it works out): 
the issue seems related to the usage of the touch event inside  `dojox.mobile.ValuePickerSlot`. Now using click event instead when clicking on the +/- buttons. Seems to be working better so far and I will get back with more info after testing more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We fixed the problem by creating a new versions of the dojox.mobile.ValuePickerSlot 
class and the dojox.mobile.ValuePickerDatePicker class.

In the MyValuePickerSlot which is a copy of ValuePickerSlot we are using click events instead touch events.
So first copy ValuePickerSlot.js and then inside MyValuePickerSlot.js you remove the following handlers:

```
// this.connect(this.plusBtnNode, touch.press, "_onTouchStart"),
// this.connect(this.minusBtnNode, touch.press, "_onTouchStart"),
```

and instead add

```
this.connect(this.plusBtnNode, "onclick", "_onClick"),
this.connect(this.minusBtnNode, "onclick", "_onClick"),
```

You can also remove the functions _onTouchStart, _onTouchMove and _onTouchEnd since you wont be using them anymore.

You now have to create a new class MyValuePickerDatePicker which inherits all functionality from the original class but you override the constructor that creates the slot classes which now are the new MyValuePickerSlot.

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare",
    "dojo/_base/lang",
    "dojox/mobile/ValuePickerDatePicker",
    "myApp/dojox-fix/MyValuePickerSlot"],
function (declare, lang,  ValuePickerDatePicker, MyValuePickerSlot) {

    return declare("myApp.dojox-fix.MyValuePickerDatePicker",[ValuePickerDatePicker], {
        //      Override of the ValuePickerDatePicker to fix a touch event bug 
        //      on Android device
        constructor: function (args) {
            this.slotClasses = [
                MyValuePickerSlot,
                MyValuePickerSlot,
                MyValuePickerSlot
            ];
            lang.mixin(this, args);
        }
    });
});
```

You can now use the MyValuePickerDatePicker in your code instead of the broken ValuePickerDatePicker.

```
<div id="dateSelectorDatePicker" data-dojo-type="myApp.dojox-fix.MyValuePickerDatePicker" data-dojo-props="slotOrder:[2,1,0]"></div>
```

A side effect is that you can't press and hold the +/- buttons if you want to scroll far; you will have to repeatedly press the button(s), but you can still type in a value, so it is not big a problem.

Comment: We're having similar problems with a worklight project using Android 5.1.1 with this ValuePicker.  It doesn't seem to reliably register the touch end events, so the values keep scrolling and scrolling.  We might try this fix.  Idan, I checked the dojo source repository online and didn't see any fixes to these files related to this potential bug.